# Android how to configure syslog (syslog.conf)

Tags: android, logging, rsyslog

I'm trying to find a way to configure syslog in android in order to send all logs to a remote server, but I can't seem to find any information about syslog in android.

I'm running android Q(API 29) and tried to search for the config file using:
`find . -name "*syslog*"`, but came up empty handed.

Is there any way this could be done in android?

Thanks for your help!